# ubuntu webkit install

Tags: ubuntu, webkit

i'm new to ubuntu 
and i want to install webkit 1.0 as dev version but i don't know what i have to do ?

Answer (score 13):

If you need development files for embedding webkit into your application you have to install libwebkit-dev package, execute this from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkit-dev
```

For Ubuntu 18.04 and later, you need:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-dev
```

Comment: Hm. Which version of ubuntu do you use? On my 9.10 there is this package. Anyway you can try something like this: apt-cache search libwebkit*-dev and there will be list of packages with names libwebkit-something-dev. Try to install them

Answer (score 7):

For ubuntu 20.04 you need:

```
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you check out this article from Ubuntu official site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebKit
It gives everything you need to get webkit up and running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Pakiet libpng12-dev nie ma dostępnej wersji, ale odnosi się do niego inny pakiet.
Zazwyczaj oznacza to, że pakietu brakuje, został zastąpiony przez inny
pakiet lub nie jest dostępny przy pomocy obecnie ustawionych źródeł.

E: Pakiet libpng12-dev nie ma kandydata do instalacji
E: Nie udało się odnaleźć pakietu libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev'
E: Nie udało się znaleźć żadnego pakietu według wyrażenia regularnego "libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev"