# How do i can install webkit in Ubuntu 10.4?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to install execute the below commands in my terminal of Ubuntu 10.4 to install webkit but my system not able to run these commands and saying command not found message

here is my terminal commands :

```
$ sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

$ sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
```

Please advice me how to install above mentioned webkit in my ubuntu system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I answered a similar question which might be useful.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16696961/1999083
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
sudo apt-get -y install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

If that doesn't work .. then I guess webkit doesn't work on Ubuntu 10.4. You at least need a 11.04 or later version.